# How can I set input value after button onclick is executed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, chakra-ui

Below is my fetching code that I put inside of the useEffect. I don't want to include inputValue inside of the [] because then the fetching would restart over and over again as I type and change the input text. I wanted the input (of the url) to initially be read only and only focus and not be read only if the edit icon is clicked. My problem is that setinputvalue is asynchronous so on buttonclick, when I setinputvalue it is undefined when I console.log inputvalue however it is not null when i console.log the previnputvalue that is within setinputvalue. Below is the fetching code:

```
data.links
    .sort((a, b) => b.order - a.order)
    .forEach((element, i) => {
      // if (element.img != "") { else { }
      setLinks((prevRows) => [
        ...prevRows,
        <Draggable
          key={element.order}
          draggableId={`draggable-${element.order}`}
          index={element.order}
        >
          {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <Flex
              direction={"column"}
              padding={3}
              justifyContent={"center"}
              alignItems={"center"}
              width={"70%"}
              backgroundColor={"#fff"}
              boxShadow={"0px 0px 3px 0px #b0b0b0"}
              borderRadius={10}
              {...provided.draggableProps}
              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
              //opacity={snapshot.isDragging ? 0.5 : 1}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
            >
              <Flex
                width={"100%"}
                justifyContent={"space-between"}
                alignItems={"center"}
              >
                <Flex
                  alignItems={"center"}
                  justifyContent={"center"}
                  gap={1}
                >
                  <Button
                    colorScheme="transparent"
                    _hover={{
                      cursor: "grab",
                      //backgroundColor: "#efefef",
                    }}
                    _active={{
                      cursor: "grabbing",
                    }}
                  >
                    <DragHandleIcon color={"black"} />
                  </Button>
                  <Flex
                    position="relative"
                    w={{ base: "100px", md: "120px", lg: "140px" }}
                    h={{ base: "60px", md: "80px", lg: "100px" }}
                    bg="transparent"
                    borderRadius="none"
                    alignItems={"center"}
                    justifyContent={"center"}
                    overflow="hidden"
                    border={"1px dashed black"}
                  >
                    {/* {"Url " + console.log(urls[i])} */}
                    {urls[i] != null ? (
                      <>
                        <Image
                          src={urls[i]}
                          alt="Selected Image"
                          objectFit="cover"
                          w="100%"
                          h="100%"
                        />
                        <IconButton
                          position="absolute"
                          top={2}
                          right={2}
                          aria-label="Remove Image"
                          icon={<CloseIcon />}
                          size="sm"
                          onClick={(e) => handleRemImg(element.order)}
                        />
                      </>
                    ) : (
                      <Box
                        p={6}
                        textAlign="center"
                        backgroundColor={"none"}
                      >
                        <Button
                          as="label"
                          htmlFor="imageInputs"
                          colorScheme="transparent"
                          _hover={{
                            backgroundColor: "#efefef",
                            cursor: "pointer",
                          }}
                          size="sm"
                          color={"black"}
                          fontSize={{
                            base: "6pt",
                            md: "8pt",
                            lg: "10pt",
                          }}
                        >
                          Select Image
                        </Button>
                        <input
                          id="imageInputs"
                          type="file"
                          accept="image/*"
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            handleImageChange3(e, element.order)
                          }
                          style={{ display: "none" }}
                        />
                      </Box>
                    )}
                  </Flex>
                  <Flex
                    direction={"column"}
                    alignItems={"flex-start"}
                    justifyContent={"center"}
                    width={"100%"}
                  >
                    <Flex maxWidth={"85%"}>
                      <Button
                        colorScheme="transparent"
                        onClick={() => {
                          setSelectedOrder(element.order);
                          setInputValue(
                            inputRefs.current[element.order].value
                          );
                          setSelectedType("url");

                          // Instead of setting the value directly, use the functional form
                          setInputValue((prevInputValue) => {
                            // You can directly use prevInputValue to compute the new value
                            // In this example, we're using it as it was in your original code
                            console.log("Input value1 = " + prevInputValue);
                            return prevInputValue;
                          });
                          console.log("Input value2 = " + inputValue);

                          // The rest of your code
                          inputRefs.current[element.order].value =
                            inputValue;
                          inputRefs.current[element.order].readOnly = false;
                          inputRefs.current[element.order].focus();
                        }}
                      >
                        <EditIcon color={"black"} />
                      </Button>
                      <Input
                        ref={(el) =>
                          (inputRefs.current[element.order] = el)
                        }
                        value={
                          // selectedOrder === i && selectedType === "url"
                          //   ? inputValue
                          //   :
                          element.title
                        }
                        border={"none"}
                        fontSize={"12pt"}
                        maxWidth={"95%"}
                        //isReadOnly={!selectedInput || selectedInput !== input}
                        isReadOnly={
                          //selectedOrder === null ||
                          selectedOrder !== element.order ||
                          selectedType !== "url"
                        }
                        //onFocus={() => setSelectedOrder(i)}
                        onBlur={() =>
                          handleInputBlur(element.order, element.title)
                        }
                        onChange={(e) => handleTextUrlChange(e, i)}
                      />
                    </Flex>
                    <Flex maxWidth={"85%"}>
                      <Button
                        colorScheme="transparent"
                        onClick={() => handleInp2(element.order)}
                      >
                        <EditIcon color={"black"} />
                      </Button>
                      <Input
                        //required
                        // readOnly={
                        //   lower == data.links.length - 1 - i
                        //     ? false
                        //     : true
                        // }
                        type={"url"}
                        onChange={(e) => setTox(e.target.value)}
                        onKeyDown={(e) =>
                          handleKeyPress(e, element.order, 1)
                        }
                        ref={(el) =>
                          (inputRefs2.current[element.order] = el)
                        }
                        border={"none"}
                        fontSize={"10pt"}
                        value={lower != element.order ? element.url : tox}
                        maxWidth={"95%"}
                      />
                    </Flex>
                  </Flex>
                </Flex>
                <Flex
                  direction={"column"}
                  alignItems={"center"}
                  justifyContent={"center"}
                  gap={5}
                >
                  <Switch
                    defaultChecked={element.active}
                    value={element.order}
                    onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                  />
                  <Button
                    borderRadius={3}
                    colorScheme="transparent"
                    _hover={{
                      backgroundColor: "#efefef",
                    }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      setDeleteIn(element.order);
                      onOpen4();
                    }}
                  >
                    <DeleteIcon color={"black"} />
                  </Button>
                </Flex>
              </Flex>
            </Flex>
          )}
        </Draggable>,
      ]);
    });
```

This is my handletexturlchange code that is used when url text is changed:

```
setInputValue(e.target.value);
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(localStorage.getItem("id"))
      .get()
      .then((val) => {
        if (val.exists) {
          const data = val.data();
          const updatedArray = data.links;
          updatedArray[i].title = e.target.value;
          db.collection("users")
            .doc(localStorage.getItem("id"))
            .update({ links: updatedArray });
        }
      });
```

Finally this is my handleinputblur code for handling when url input is focused away

```
setSelectedType("");
    setInputValue("");
    setSelectedOrder(null);
    inputRefs.current[ind].value = titul;
    inputRefs.current[ind].readOnly = true;
```